# TextView não centraliza no android 4.1.1

Tags: android

Estou com um problema no meu *layout*, na API 16 ( 4.1.1 ) o `TextView` não fica centralizado. Estou utilizando `ConstraintLayout`.

As propriedades no XML esta assim:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txv_textomeio"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:text="@string/textoinicial"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_iniciar"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txv_certo"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.503" />
```

[image: como deveria ficar]
[image: Como fica]

Comment: @DanielGentil nao funcionou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere a propriedade `layout_width` para `match_parent`.

Em vez de:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:textAlignment="center"
```

Coloque:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
```

Comment: Já tinha feito isso, sem sucesso, continua alinhado a esquerda

Comment: @IgorOliveira eu peguei seu mesmo código e inseri aqui e funcionou certinho com essa alteração. xD

Comment: @IgorOliveira coloque também `android:gravity="center"`

Comment: Aqui está funcionando com textAlignment e gravity normalmente... Verifique se seu TextView não está dentro de uma view que esteja wrap_content na largura?

Comment: Esta dentro de um constraintlayout com match_parent, tentei fazer isso que você disse, porem sem sucesso tambem.

Comment: Vou tentar colocar dentro de um linear layout

Comment: O view pai também deve estar match_parent

Comment: Consegui, eu estava editando o xml v21, perdão pelo vacilo